# Handle default locale on Next 13 App Router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, next.js13, next-translate

I have a project using Next 13 app router and pages router at same time, I'm using `next-translate` as my i18n package but I'm facing a problem with the pages generated by app router

I want my default locale to open without having a prefix
Example:
fr/blog > fr/blog
en/blog > /blog

This works fine on my pages generated by page router, my homepage opens as `localhost:3000` for the en version and `localhost:3000/fr` for the fr version, but when it comes to the app router pages, it just not work - my translations are being translated but I need to pass the prefix in every scenario

fr/blog works
en/blog works
/blog redirects me to a 404 (should open normally with EN as the locale)

How can I handle this on Next 13 using `next-translate`? I build a simple example on github so you're able to check: https://github.com/mbaldas/default-locale-issue

1. Start the application - npm run dev
2. Go to http://localhost:3000/en/test-router/slugish-url and verify that runs fine
3. Go to http://localhost:3000/fr/test-router/slugish-url and verify that runs fine
4. Go to http://localhost:3000/test-router/slugish-url and verify that it redirects to a 404